# How to connect two MLX90614 sensors to Raspberry Pi 3 B+?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, i2c

I connected one MLX90614 sensor to Raspberry Pi 3 (which communicate by i2c bus) according to videos on youtube. Everything was fine, it was working. But then a need connect the same MLX90614 sensor (i2c bus too). These sensors will be next to each other and they will be used for counting people in enclosed rooms. So, the first sensor will register people going into the rooms and the second sensor will register people going outside. Please, could you give me some advice, how to connect these sensors? For now, only one of them is working....Thank you.

Comment: Read the sensor's datasheet - you'll have to confiure a different address for each sensor so they will not collide. I think that the question should be asked [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem, not software.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every MLX90614 has a default I2C address of 0x5A, but that address can be re-written -- one of the major features supported by the device. By reconfiguring the address of an MLX90614, you can add multiple devices (up to 127!) to the same bus to get a larger temperature map.

Please refer to [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/mlx90614-ir-thermometer-hookup-guide/all%23:%7E:text%3DSMBus%2520(I2C)%26text%3DEvery%2520MLX90614%2520has%2520a%2520default,features%2520supported%2520by%2520the%2520device.&ved=2ahUKEwiyk6K33532AhW-T2wGHcRyD4sQFnoECAQQBQ&usg=AOvVaw2-uPMNJH2k17nVo77mYzc3) for details.